# Error undefined symbols when call class Objective C from Swift UI test

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Possible duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086669/call-an-objective-c-class-from-a-swift-test-file) but I can't find the answer
My project is used `Objective C`, and I create ui test in `swift`.
Then I create a bridging header **MyApp_Bridging_Header.h** file like this:

```
 #ifndef MyApp_Bridging_Header_h
 #define MyApp_Bridging_Header_h
 #import "MyService.h"

 #endif /* MyApp_Bridging_Header_h */
```

And call the class in `Swift` test:

```
 func testApp() {
   // singleton
   var service = MyService.shared()
 }
```

Xcode can regconize `MyService` class, but when I run test, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyService", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyAppUITests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any idea to fix this error?

Comment: Maybe quit xcode, then deleting Derived Data, cleaning build folder and then clean project. and try building.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64?rq=1

Comment: @PranavKasetti Tried all, still not work. And I don't use any framework, it's only ui test, and it refers to MyApp

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935640/xcode-unittest-build-failed-with-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa?

Comment: @PranavKasetti still not work. I already search for them

Comment: Could you share code for MyService class?

Comment: Hmm, could you explain also which steps you have tried as well, would help me to better understand.

Comment: @PranavKasetti sorry for late response, I finally fix it. The reason is that I didn't add `MyService` class into UITest target's build source. It's fixed in Xcode->Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources
Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: @ductran my issue was the same. You may want to write an answer and accept it for visibility!