# Failing trying to use Objective-C library in my Swift project with bridging header

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I think I have completed all the necessary steps for this, but it fails for some reason.
This is the error I get:

> Showing All Messages Undefined symbol:
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_HCKBeaconCentralManager

[image]

I have set the file in Build Settings:

[image]

This is the content of bridge file:

```
#import "HCKBeaconCentralManager.h"
#import "HCKBeaconInterface.h"
#import "HCKBeaconBaseModel.h"
#import "HCKBeaconProtocol.h"
```

Just in case this is code I use to try to call the SDK classes:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreBluetooth

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate,HCKCentralScanDelegate {

    func centralManagerScanNewDeviceModel(_ beaconModel: HCKBeaconBaseModel!, manager: HCKBeaconCentralManager!) {
        print("centralManagerScanNewDeviceModel")
    }

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        print("scene init")
        HCKBeaconCentralManager.sharedInstance()?.scanDelegate = self
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086669/call-an-objective-c-class-from-a-swift-test-file

Comment: Try this post for my specific problem? or try it as a general guide on how to implement bridge header? If the latter one then I believe it is the same as all the other guides. Or maybe I'm missing some crucial step, if so I don't see it.

Comment: I understand your question. I saw the similarities with your question in the post I provided.

Comment: Did you add the objective-c files into `Xcode->Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources`?

Comment: No. This was the missing step. Great now it seems to compile correctly. Thank You!

Comment: Then I add this as an answer so the question could be fulfilled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your Objective-C files into Xcode->Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources.

Comment: Your answer save my live Thanks man I don't know why apple didn't mention this

Comment: If you are building Swift in XCode, and you dragged and dropped a folder of objective C modules into your project, XCode may not add those objective C .m files onto the project's target build list.  You can manually add a group (folder) to the project and add those objective C files into the group. Then XCode will add them to the target build list.